# Как вернуть ключ разработчика?

Tags: android-studio

Проблема. В студии был сохранен ключ разработчика для подписи приложений. После поломки ноутбука данные были стёрты. Как вернуть ключ? Доступ к аккаунту есть. Есть уже выложенные приложения

Comment: Написать в техподдержку?

Comment: правильный ответ - никак. вам прямо при загрузке приложения пишут это.

Comment: Стойте. А нельзя ли вырвать папку meta-inf из apk и сунуть в выкладываемый?

Comment: @СергейГрушин тогда бы каждый желающий мог так сделать. И в чём в таком случае был бы смысл подписи?

Comment: если ключ утерян, то восстановить его нет никакой возможности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Никак.

Google не хранит ваш приватный ключ. Только его необратимые производные, вроде публичного ключа и его отпечатка.

Подпись же специально придумана для того, чтобы защитить пользователей от публикации сборок, измененных злоумышленником без ключа, которым подписана уже имеющаяся у пользователей версия. Сейчас этим "злоумышленником" пытаетесь быть вы. К сожалению для вас, меры против таких атак приняты уже давно и неотключаемы.